# Core Data: What should I use as a Sort Descriptor with ordered set (ios5) in a many to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

[image]- I have an `Item` Entity and a `Tag` Entity.
- Items can have multiple Tags and Tags can be linked to multiple Items (many to many relationship).
- The relationship is an "Ordered Relationship" (using Ordered relationship in IOS5) both ways.

I want to fetch all child tags for a given item

Im using the following fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];

// Fetch all items that have a given tag
Tag* myTag = ....;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tag == %@", myTag];

// This is my attempt to get the correct sort ordering (it crashes)
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tag"
                                                                 ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
```

The above sort descriptor returns data (which I assume is in some order) but then crashes:

```
[_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b058f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet compare:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x10b058f0'
```

If I give an empty sort descriptors array then I dont get a crash but the result is not ordered.

How do I correctly implement the sort descriptor in a many to many relationship using the ordered relationship feature in ios5?

Comment: Can you clarify what Entity you are fetching instances of? If you're fetching instances of `Item`, then the sort descriptor is to determine the sort order of the `Item`s and has nothing to do with the ordered relationship `Item` has to `Tag`. The exception is caused because your keyPath doesn't end in an attribute but a set. Try `tags.@count` for example instead.

Comment: I have a similar query. In this case, I am looking for all Items associated with Tag (fetch request on Item entity) and since Tag to Item is an ordered relationship, I want to fetch Items linked with Tags "in the order" it was saved in the database. Coredata does not expose the intermediate table used for maintaining the ordered relationship, so how to specify that in the NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: I am trying to fetch all instances of Items linked to a Tag intance in the order it was saved. I am printing out the sql query to the console and if i use tags as the sort descriptor, i can see the result is ordered by an intermediate table , however this is internal to core data.  Is there anyway to specify this order using the sort descriptor?

SELECT DISTINCT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZKDITEM t0 JOIN Z_2TAGS t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_2ITEMS WHERE  t1.Z_4TAGS = ? ORDER BY t1.Z_FOK_2ITEMS

Comment: can you give a little more description about how you want it to sort? it was crashing before because "keys" isn't a property, its a relationship.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you may be misapprehending what an ordered relationship means in Core Data. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346073/what-does-the-ordered-flag-do-in-a-to-many-relationship), "ordered" doesn't mean "with regards to some property" - instead, "ordered" means "preserves the user's order" (or another specific order that would otherwise seem arbitrary). Some examples:

- An ordered relationship would be good for steps in a recipe (the example from Apple's [Core Data Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2)) - the steps couldn't necessarily be ordered with respect to any of their properties (e.g. their text), and would have to maintain an "index" or "order" property on their own if Core Data didn't do the ordering.
- An ordered relationship would *not* be good for a list of names - the user could choose to sort by first or last names, for example, and the collection of names has no real intrinsic ordering internally. The only thing that matters is display order - the data itself doesn't need to maintain that order. (The rule of thumb in Apple's docs is that if a user could conceivably choose between sort specifiers, the relationship *shouldn't* be ordered in Core Data.)

In your case, you try to apply a sort descriptor to the *set of ordered sets* (the values for the `tags` property) that you're fetching. This is the cause of your crash - the NSOrderedSet subclass (`_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet`, in your case) doesn't implement the `-compare:` method that the sort descriptor would use to sort them, and so you get that exception.

I think a good solution for you would be to *not use* a sort descriptor at all; instead, if you want to change the preserved ordering for display to the user, get the NSOrderedSet value for `tags` on some Item, then get an array out of it with your own sort using [`-sortedArrayUsingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009980-CH2-SW5). This will keep the data in the right order in Core Data but let you reorder it yourself programmatically.

At a higher level, you may also want to consider whether or not you really need order in your relationships. It incurs a significant performance penalty, and all you really get back is the original order in which tags were added to items (or vice versa). If you intend to change that order every time you display the tags, then you're taking that performance hit for no real benefit - make your relationships unordered, then either continue sorting programmatically or use a sort descriptor on an aggregate key, such as `tags.@count`, as suggested in the comments.