# CoreData: Sort items by index in category's set

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data

I have a simple catalog manager functionality with items in categories EXCEPT one Item can be in several Categories.

**Item** has 'parents' key which is NSSet of parent categories

**Category** has 'items' key which is NSOrderedSet of its subitems

I am using `NSFetchedResultController` and its delegate to fill my table with items

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY parents == %@)", self.category];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[????????];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

So using this code I can get the list of items in self.category

In my UI I have `Drag and Drop` functionality. So I can move Items inside categories.

**My question:** Category1 and Category2 both contain references to the same items Item1 and Item2. I need to have Item1, Item2 order in Category1 and Item2, Item1 order in Category2. That's why I made category.items property as `NSOrderedSet`.

But I just cannot sort Items by their index in category.items

I tried to use blocks in sort descriptors - didn't work, I tried to use selectors in sort descriptors - didn't work, I tried to subclass sort descriptors - works somehow but doesn't update Items when I am changing their index it category.items.
Like this in my NSSortDescriptorSubclass:

`- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(Item*)object1 toObject:(Item*)object2 {`

```
int index1 = [self.category.items indexOfObject:object1];
int index2 = [self.category.items indexOfObject:object2];

if (index1 > index2) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
} else if (index1 < index2) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}

return NSOrderedSame;
```

}

But items order won't be updated in my UI if I change order in Category.items

So please, help me to sort items by their index in category.items set. Maybe there is a way to do that through some keys, operators, expressions, anything else. Thanks.

Comment: And you insist on using NSFetchedResultsController? Since you already have a self.category. Accessing items in that ordered set in their index order is simple as calling -objectAtIndex: in your data source method.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use it because I'd like my items to be automatically updated when I change some properties from other parts of the app

Comment: Alright. A sort descriptor with a comparator block will definitely work for a one-time sort. The difficult part is to have NSFetchedResultsController know about change in relationship order. I am not aware of a way that could accomplish that.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use blocks for sort descriptors in CoreData. It simply generates an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you do not use ordered to-many relationships. It seems that they are not really working as expected and do not fit your needs.

Instead, you need to introduce your own attribute to do the sorting. You could have an entity `categoryItem` that has to-one relationships to both `Category` and `Item` as well as an attribute `sequence`.

In your FRC you fetch the `categoryItem` entity and when displaying you just use `categoryItem.item` to access the properties of the item. When you reorder (e.g. via drag and drop) you have to renumber all `categoryItem`s and assign the correct sequence number.

-- EDIT --

To mark the `categoryItem` as "dirty" when some detail of an item changes: you can implement a method `markDirty` in `categoryItem` that looks like this:

```
// CategoryItem.m
-(void)markDirty {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"sequence"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"sequence"];
}

// EditItemController.m
item.attribute = newAttribute; 
for (CategoryItem *i in item.categoryItems) { [i markDirty]; }
```

Comment: that might work! thank you very much! let me try to implement that and mark you answer as correct. thanks

Comment: do you know a workaround the problem which your solution produces: now if I change some parameters in an item my table view is not updated (it will be updated only when categoryItem parameter are changed)

Comment: Yes, a subtle issue. You can try the workaround in my edited answer. Did you try a simple `[tableView reloadData];` or perhaps also `[self.frc performFetch:self.frc.fetchRequest error:nil];`?

Comment: btw, I decided to implement your `markDirty` solution, because it updates just one row in my table view instead of all, and as long as I have images from urls there it would be definitely better to update just one record. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One to many relationships in Core Data are `NSSet`s, not`NSOrderedSet`s. The index of an item in a category is not saved for this reason. You can add another entity to your Core Data model called, something like `IndexValue`. `IndexValue` would have two attributes, `categoryId` or `categoryName` (whichever makes sense) and then `categoryIndex`. `Item` would then have a one to many relationship with this entity (and a one to one inverse relationship, as there is no need to reuse these entities, they should be unique). For each `Category` that `Item` is in, an `IndexValue` would be created.

**EDIT:** It seems an ordered property was added to support `NSOrderedSet` one to many relationships in [OS X 10.7 and iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html). This must be what you are targeting and using. The documentation is sparse on this feature, but order should be persisted without the need to use `NSSortDescriptor`s when fetching the relationship. As far as changing the order goes, I'm not sure how this is supported. [Performance on large sets of data is lower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354522/387576) using this method compared to the above method I outlined as well.

Comment: That is not entirely true. Ordered relationships are available from iOS5. You can convert an ordinary relationship (which is NSSet based) to an ordered relationship (NSOrderedSet based) by setting ordered flag in relationship property in your data model.

Comment: Yes, this is true, they have added this ordered checkbox so I would like to use it